# Shortest walk that covers $k$ nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard, shortest-path

I have the following problem, I would like to know an efficient algorithm to solve it.

Suppose I have a weighted graph $G$ and a set of vertices $K$, I want to find a walk which starts at a vertex $s$ and visits at least once every vertex of $K$ such that the distance is minimized.

There is **no** constraint on repeated nodes or edges in the walk found and is not guaranteed that the graph does not contain cycles. Some people have suggested me that it maybe NP-Hard due to a reduction from TSP, but there is no restriction of visit vertices exactly once, and is well known that TSP have that.

Comment: I think TSP (with the constraint you point out that each vertex can be visited only once) would reduce to your problem. This would imply your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: You mention TSP: is your graph weighted? If so, the question should say so.

Comment: I have Edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple reduction from Hamiltonian path. Suppose we are given a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, and want to know whether it contains a Hamiltonian path. Adjoin a new vertex $s$ and connect it to all other vertices. The new graph $G'$ contains a walk of length (at most) $n$ starting at $s$ and covering all vertices if and only if the original graph $G$ contains a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: What if the graph is weighted as David Richerby suggested? Indeed, the problem makes more sense if $G$ is weighted. I think in that case NP-hardness comes from the TSP problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed the graph is weighted, I've edited the question. But even if the graph is not weighted, how that reduction works?, in the sense of where is the **K** set of vertices of the original question?

Comment: The set $K$ consists simply of *all* vertices. Allowing weights only makes the problem more difficult, so we might as well assume there are none.

Comment: The weight constraint can be satisfied by getting the shortest distance between all the nodes in the Graph, then a new Graph $G'$ can be constructed like Yuval suggests and the weights must be the minimum that were found before, and it would be reduction from TSP. I think it would work that way.